# HUGO range function with dynamic value

Tags: html, hugo

I have a list page, where contents needs to be rendered based upon value from URL.

this is my current implementation, I am able to render the contents but only for one taxonomy (i.e) technology.

```
      {{ range .Site.Taxonomies.categories.technology }}
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 blog-card has-border">
        {{ .Render "article" }}
      </div>
      {{ end }}
```

I tried to use the below method to get the string from URL, but its not working.

```
  {{ $category:= urls.Parse .Permalink }}
      <p>{{ $category.Path }}</p>
 {{ range .Site.Taxonomies.categories $category }}
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 blog-card has-border">
        {{ .Render "article" }}
      </div>
      {{ end }}
```

For example the URL is

> localhost/public/categories/technology/

I want to get the technology and append it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a category list page... which should only use:

```
{{ range .RegularPages }}
...
{{ end }}
```

But to answer your question... the following should work:

```
{{ $category := index (split .RelPermalink "/") 3 }}
```